# Is through dependencies only we include external jar of an application into maven project?

Tags: maven, dependencies

Is through dependencies only we  include external jar of an application into maven project.
Should we use systempath tag to do so???

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I think you need to be more specific in order to attract meaningful answers. Try to be more verbose in explaining your problem. Right now it's a bit open to interpretation. For example, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If you need an external jar in a Maven project, you draw it from a Maven Repository (Nexus/Artifactory) through a dependency entry in your pom. Using system path dependencies is discouraged.